# Android Phonegap: open pdf file

Tags: android, cordova

i am very very new in android phonegap. i want to open pdf file from my sdcard.
i am using this link

http://www.giovesoft.com/2011/08/download-and-open-pdf-with-phonegap.html

here, that pdf file stored in sdcard, while i try to open that file mean its shows the following error message in my logcat

PdfViewer: Error loading url

```
/sdcard/Downloads/:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] 
dat=file:///sdcard/Downloads typ=application/pdf flg=0x4000000 }
```

any one can help me?

Comment: Have u checked ur sd card path currectly?

Comment: make sure you have a pdf viewer application installed, i have a working application here - https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/android-cordova-download/

Comment: yes i checked my sdcard path within my pdf file is available

Comment: hai dhaval i downloaded that file from that link, but its also "The file pat is not valid" error.

Comment: 05-24 23:30:36.175: ERROR/SensorManager(952): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA220 delay= 120 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4a4d3198
05-24 23:30:36.175: ERROR/SensorHAL(176): Sensor Input open fd_compass=106 fd_accel=107
05-24 23:30:36.185: ERROR/SensorManager(952): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
05-24 23:30:36.185: ERROR/SensorHAL(952): __data_data_open  27 29
05-24 23:30:36.185: ERROR/SensorHAL(176): Write acc delay /sys/class/input/input3/poll_delay <---60
  in logcat it shows this type error

Answer (score 0):

Now the above proble is solved, here my code:

```
public String showPdf(String fileName) {     
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Log.d("PdfViewer", "list: " + file.exists());
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {               
                 Intent intent = new Intent();                
                 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                this.ctx.startActivity(intent);  

                Log.d("PdfViewerr", "read: " + fileName);
                return "";
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("PdfViewer: Error loding url "+fileName+":"+ e.toString());
                Log.d("PdfViewer", "error: " + fileName);
                return e.toString();
            }       

        }else{
            Log.d("PdfViewer", "notfound: " + fileName);
            return "file not found";
        }        
    }
```